# Trying to use a Google Maps user interface to caputre Lat/Lon in Django

Tags: javascript, django, google-maps, user-interface, geocoding

I'm a Django newbie, and learning quickly. But I just can't figure out how to get this [simple Google Maps user interface](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/examples/geocoding-extraction.html) to pass the resulting lat/lon into my database. Can anyone help?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851722/get-physical-map-location-of-object-based-off-user-input

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Django, but the general principle for passing data from a client side Google Map to a server side database is to send the data from the client to a server using a GDownloadUrl() call. Write a separate dedicated server that accepts data from the client, writes it to the database and does nothing else.

Alternatively, you could make HTTP geocoding calls directly from your server side script, and not bother with displaying a Google Map at all during the data capture phase. Obviously, you have to eventually display the geocoded information on a publicly accessible Google Map in order to comply with Google's Terms.